# Neighbor function with two+ grouping variables in Clickhouse doesn't work

Tags: sql, window-functions, clickhouse

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 date          channel    sum
    2021-01-02    Media      1200
    2021-01-02    Direct     2300
    2021-01-01    Media      800
    2021-01-01    Direct     900
```

I want to use standard lag() function for each row to display the sum from the previous day for a certain channel. So the table will look like this:

```
 date          channel    sum   prev
2021-01-02    Media      1200   800
2021-01-02    Direct     2300   900
2021-01-01    Media      800    500
2021-01-01    Direct     900    600
```

I am using Clickhouse version below 21.3 so I cannot use any standard window functions. I tried to use neighbour() function but it doesn't work with more than one grouping variable – results are wrong:

```
SELECT event_date,
       channel,
       neighbor(sum, -1) as prev
from example
group by event_date, channel
```

Please help!

Comment: it's expected, because neighbor is not aggregating function. You may use a trick and sort data by channel, event_date and reset neighbor result using if because channel <> prev channel. Though it is much much productive to use arrays https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/lag-lead/#using-arrays

Comment: I did not figure out how to use arrays with two grouping variable

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `neighbor` function query can look like this:

```sql
SELECT
    event_date,
    channel,
    sum,
    if(neighbor(channel, 1) = channel, neighbor(sum, 1), -1) AS prev
FROM
(
    SELECT event_date, channel, sum
    FROM example
    ORDER BY
        channel DESC,
        event_date DESC
)
```

Notice that you should set the 'default' value for rows when the `channel` is changed (I choose `-1`)